# How do I split the letters and numbers to 2 arrays from a string in PHP

Tags: php

I would like to know how to split both letters and numbers in 2 separate arrays, for example if I have `$string = "2w5d15h9s";`, then I want it to become

```
$letters = ["w", "d", "h", "s"];

$numbers = [2, 5, 15, 9];
```

Anybody got any idea of how to do it?

I'm basically trying to make a ban command and I want to make it so you can specify a time for the ban to expire.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `preg_split`:

```
$string = "2w5d15h9s";
$letters = preg_split("/\d+/", $string);
array_shift($letters);
print_r($letters);
$numbers = preg_split("/[a-z]+/", $string);
array_pop($numbers);
print_r($numbers);
```

This prints:

```
Array
(
    [0] => w
    [1] => d
    [2] => h
    [3] => s
)

Array
(
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 5
    [2] => 15
    [3] => 9
)
```

Note that I am using `array_shift` or `array_pop` above to remove empty array elements which arise from the regex split.  These empty entries occur because, for example, when spitting on digits the first character is a digit, which leaves behind an empty array element to the left of the first actual letter.

Answer (score 0):

Using `preg_split()` with a `PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY` flag is the most concise way that I can think of.

In terms of efficiency, `preg_` functions are not famous for being fast. Scanning the string should arguably be done in one pass, but these micro-optimization considerations are probably not worth toiling over for such small input strings.

As for the patterns, `\d+` means one or more consecutive digit characters and `\D+` means one or more consecutive non-digit characters.  The `0` is the limit parameter, which merely informs the function to have no limit (split the string as many times as it can).

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/cZAdp))

```
$string = "2w5d15h9s";
var_export(preg_split('/\d+/', $string, 0, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY)); // get non-numbers
var_export(preg_split('/\D+/', $string, 0, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY)); // get numbers
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'w',
  1 => 'd',
  2 => 'h',
  3 => 's',
)
array (
  0 => '2',
  1 => '5',
  2 => '15',
  3 => '9',
)
```